# Capybara chooses wrong format in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, capybara

I am new to Rails and TDD.
I am currently stuck on testing my page with Capybara and RSpec.

I have a **form** on home page (root_path) that submits via post to Linkage controller :

```
<%= form_for @link, url: linkages_path, method: :post,  remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.labels/text_fields... %>
    <%= f.submit "Add Link" %>
<%  end %>
```

It gets to the **Linkages controller**'s create action and 
ideally should change the root_path's data with AJAX (format.js):

```
  def create
    @link = Link.new(params[:link])
    if @link.save and current_user.linkages.build(link_id: @link.id).save
      flash.now[:success] = "Link to \"#{@link.content}\" was successfully added!"
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect root_path }
        format.js do
            @user_linkage = current_user.linkages
            render 'users/user_linkage.js.erb'
        end
      end
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "..."
      error...
    end
  end
```

Now on success it should render the js file users/user_linkage.js.erb,
which is this (it just changes the userLinkage div in root_path):

```
$('#flash').html("<%= escape_javascript(raw(flash_display)) %>");
$('#userLinkage').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'users/user_linkage_items',
                                             locals: {user_linkage: @user_linkage }) %>");
```

And it works perfectly in Chrome/Firefox/IE/Opera.
However when I write the test for it in **Capybara** (below) it fails because it
redirects back to the root_path (format.html), instead of rendering the 
page specified in format.js block (changing the data in root_path).

```
describe "test" do

    let(:link){'some link'}
    let(:text){'some text'}

    before do
        visit root_path
        fill_in 'Text', with: link
        fill_in 'Link', with: text
    end

    it "should work" do

        expect do
            click_button 'Add Link'
        end.to change(Link, :count).by(1)
        sleep(5)
        should have_content(text)                 # works until here (root_path has same info)
        should have_selector('div.alert-success') # fails on this line(flash message)
    end
end
```

So I know that Capybara can only do the GET request, and my form is in POST, but as to the user simulation that stuff should be irrelevant(?).

If I change my formats on success from format.html/format.js to the following:

```
  respond_to do |format|
    format.all do
        @user_linkage = current_user.linkages
        render 'users/user_linkage.js.erb'
    end
  end
```

, then Capybara finally renders me the correct page, but if I call the `save_and_open_page`
on it, then I see all the escaped javascript and incorrectly rendered HTML, so I cannot test
for something like `have_selector()`.

My question is why is that happening?
Is it because Capybara uses GET instead of POST and even clicking the link wont necessarily call the right format inside of a controller?

P.S. Switching format.html with format.js (ordering) does not do the trick - the format.html is getting called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK Capybara is fine with POST. Add `:js => true` if you're using capybara-webkit. 
In your js you need `.html_safe`:

```
$('#userLinkage').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'users/user_linkage_items',
                                         locals: {user_linkage: @user_linkage }).html_safe %>");
```

Also this:

```
current_user.linkages.build(link_id: @link.id).save
```

could be changed to:

```
current_user.linkages.create(link_id: @link.id)
```

Also follow some constant indentation scheme(2 spaces is common used).

Comment: Thanks a lot!  It was a problem of using javascript with Capybara. I have tried Selenium instead of Capybara-webkit (seems like it fails for a lot of people on Win 7) and watched this [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/257-request-specs-and-capybara) on how to set it up, and it worked great after some initial tweaking. Thank you for all the suggestions ;)

Comment: Great, glad you figured that out. Selenium is really brings less troubles sometimes but it's slow.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `js: true` to your test.

```
it "should work", js: true do
```